# Configure Apache Spark for AWS EKS

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, amazon-eks

I'd like to start working with apache spark on k8s but I don't have experience with it.
I installed Spark via Helm chart with ServiceType "LoadBalancer".

```sh
spark-submit --master 'spark://LOADBALANCER.elb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:7077' \ 
--deploy-mode client \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image='MY_IMAGE' test.py
```

This is my test code test.py

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark_session = SparkSession.builder \
    .getOrCreate()
l = [('Alice', 1)]
spark_session.createDataFrame(l).show()
```

Running locally on microk8s cluster works but the same way on AWS EKS cluster fails with following endless log warning

```
22/02/16 17:36:01 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks resource profile 0
22/02/16 17:36:16 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

Is there a way to develop the user code and run it against the kubernetes cluster or should I create a new docker image everytime? Maybe there are some best practices for Apache Spark on EKS?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change to `--deploy-mode cluster`